# shoulda matcher and conditional validation errors

Tags: ruby, rspec, shoulda

Here I use the attribute `:new_record` to set the condition for validation.

```
attr_accessor :new_record
validates :email, presence: true, email: true, unless: :new_record?

  def new_record?
    @new_record || true
  end
```

if the new_record? == true, the email validation will be skipped and new user is valid.
I wrote this test: 
`it { expect(subject).to validate_presence_of(:email) }`
and it returns error:

```
Failure/Error: it { expect(subject).to validate_presence_of(:email) }

       User did not properly validate that :email cannot be empty/falsy.
         After setting :email to ‹nil›, the matcher expected the User to be
         invalid, but it was valid instead.
```

Note that this test run perfectly if there is no condition added to the validation. Also, the code work well in production.
I also have tried

```
    before(:each) do
      subject.new_record = true
    end
```

or

```
`before { allow(subject).to receive(:new_record?).and_return(true) }`
```

Can any one help?

Comment: `@new_record || true` will never return false.

Comment: I set the default new_record as true as default, when I need to create a new user and new_record as false when I need to edit the user profile. new_record == true this test should be passed if email is nil -> user.valid? == false. However, the result from test is "After setting :email to ‹nil›, the matcher expected the User to be
         invalid, but it was valid instead."

Comment: Why don't u use `on: :create`?

Comment: That's a great idea instead of my new_record thing. However, I just try adding on: :create after `validates :email, presence: true, email: true, on: :create`. It failed with the same error. (Test passed before ading on: :create)

Comment: You need also to change your spec for smth like this: `expect(subject).to validate_presence_of(:email).on(:create)`.

Comment: It works like a charm. Thank you a lot.